# why is dd with direct flag much slower than dsync

Tags: linux, filesystems, ceph

I was trying to use dd to test the performance of my ceph filesystem. During testing, I found something confusing, that is, dd with oflag=dsync or conv=fdatasync/fsync is around 10 times faster than dd with oflag=direct.

My network is 2*10Gb

```
/mnt/testceph# dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/testceph/test1  bs=1G count=1 oflag=direct
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 23.1742 s, 46.3 MB/s


/mnt/testceph# dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/testceph/test1  bs=1G count=1 conv=fdatasync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 2.22468 s, 483 MB/s
```

Comment: Were you ever able to gather `iostat` output?

Answer (score 8):

> dd with oflag=dsync or conv=fdatasync/fsync is around 10 times faster than dd with oflag=direct

`conv=fdatasync` / `conv=fsync` still mean I/O is initially queued to the kernel cache and destaged to disk as the kernel sees fit. This gives the kernel a big opportunity to merge I/Os, create parallel submission out of I/O that has yet to be destaged and generally decouples I/O submission to the kernel from I/O acceptance by the disk (to the extent that buffering will allow). Only when `dd` has finished sending ALL the data will it have to wait for anything still only in cache to be flushed to disk (and with `fsync` that includes any metadata).

`oflag=dsync` is still allowed to make use of kernel buffering - it just causes a flush+wait for completion after each submission. Since you are sending only one giant write this will put you into near enough the same scenario as doing `conv=fdatasync` above.

When you specify `oflag=odirect` you are saying "trust that all my parameters are sensible and turn off as much kernel buffering as you can". In your case a `bs` that huge is nonsensical with `odirect` as your "disk"'s maximum transfer block size (let alone the optimal size) is almost certainly smaller. You'll likely trigger splitting but [due to memory requirements on `O_DIRECT` the splitting points may lead to smaller I/Os](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/533845/109111) than the above cases.

It's hard to tell for sure what's going on though. Really we would need to see how the I/O was leaving the bottom of the kernel (e.g. by comparing `iostat` output during runs) to get a better idea of what's going on.

TLDR; maybe using `odirect` is leading to smaller sized I/Os leaving the kernel and thus causing worse performance in your scenario?

Comment: Which one of these options is closest to a write via e.g. `cp`? I'd like to use the speed output of `dd` to measure write speeds.